# What is this statue in Star Wars Rogue One?

Tags: analysis, star-wars, rogue-one

In [*Rogue One* (2016)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3748528/), when transitioning to the planet Jedha, there's shown an extremely large, fallen statue of someone.

Who is this a statue of, what's their significance, and why is it now in ruins?

[image]

Comment: Similar question on Sci-Fi.SE: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149596/whats-the-story-behind-the-fallen-statue-on-jedha

Answer (score 36, accepted):

According to the [Starwars Wikia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedha):

### Who

That is an un-named Jedi.

[image: Fallen ruins of a statue depicting a Jedi]

### Significance

I believe the point of this shot is to show 2 things:

1. Jedi are an ancient and (once) great religion
2. This planet was once significant to Jedi

### Why is it now in ruins

> As more of the galaxy was mapped, more direct hyperspace routes were
>   discovered. These new passages made the old, winding routes, such as
>   those connecting with Jedha, obsolete. The once-popular Jedha became
>   an antiquated curiosity rather than a relevant destination, a location
>   for those who desired spiritual guidance, a deeper purpose, or to
>   simply exile themselves from the larger galaxy.

Comment: Interesting - I never thought of this as fallen, but as a deliberate shaping of landscape to create a sort of best-viewed-from-the-air ground attraction. But a fallen statue probably makes more sense come to think of it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Impressive materials if it fell and held that shape...

Comment: @TimB Indeed  Probably petrified midichlorians or something

Comment: Like the route 66 of the Star Wars universe.